# Why ln -s copied a file instead of linking it?

Tags: symlink, dropbox, ln

Please see the screenshot.
For two times I have run ln -s and it creates a copy of a small text file instead of linking it.
The exact command I have run is:

```
lobianco@lobianco-officeLaptopLatitude:~/Dropbox/Documenti/Varie/lef/papers/ffsm++/versions/07_carbon_balance_with_multipliers$ ln -s ../../../00_common/biblio.bib .
```

Having thought that the problem is with using the . syntax, I have run the command:

```
lobianco@lobianco-officeLaptopLatitude:~/Dropbox/Documenti/Varie/lef/papers/ffsm++/versions/07_carbon_balance_with_multipliers$ ln -s ../../../00_common/biblio.bib bibliolink.bib
```

At that time I effectively had a link. But at that point, I have re-run the first command, and again I had a link, even using the . syntax!
So, what did happened?

[image: screenshot]

(Note: Unfortunately I don't have a screenshot of the two files initially copied, but I am sure it was a copy and not a link. Aside Nautilus telling me it was a text file and not a link, I have opened both the original and the copy with Kate and tested that changes in the original didn't propagate to the copy. I am using Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show, but you *could* have this on a mounted filesystem which doesn't support symbolic links.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I didn't specified, but it's a normal ext3 filesys.

Answer (score 1):

I only can guess cause of having no dropbox install, but did you check if the dropbox daemon will change a symbolic link to a real file ?

Comment: Not normally, as symbolic links pointing to a file that it also resides within the sync folder are left as such. That's said, I too suspect that it must have been some sort of interaction with the dropbox daemon to have caused such behaviour.. good to know..